# Xamarin Android Resource Designer Missing IDs

Tags: xamarin.android, android-resources

We are doing some work around sharing UI across apps, both entire views and also individual controls, so the structure we end up with is (on Android):

```
Android App

    View (Activity + Layout) pulled in from a NuGet package

        Control (Layout) pulled in from another NuGet package
```

So the app pulls in the view and the view pulls in the control.

The problem we’ve seen is that resource IDs defined in the control’s layout don’t end up in the Resource.designer.cs of the app such that when the app runs we see a crash when FindViewByID is called.

Interestingly we have implemented the above in three different apps, it works in two and not the other, so I’m left thinking it is ever a difference in the build config somewhere or its pure chance and we can’t rely on this pattern working.

Has anyone seen this before?

Update:

Having paid closer attention to the build output I can actually see warnings being generated for the missing controls:

```
Warning XA0106: Skipping MyControl.Resource.Id.myId. Please check that 
your Nuget Package versions are compatible. (XA0106)
```

Comment: What was your solution?

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: I have found online that the nuget package warnings are from another package depending on an older version of Xamarin.Forms.  

See JimmyGarrido's response here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/89661/a-lot-of-warnings-appear-in-a-new-empty-xamarin-forms-xaml-project

Answer (score 0):

Old question I know, but in case anyone needs it:

I experienced very similar problems after updating to Xamarin.Forms v4.1.0.581479, and followed James Esh's comment above, and JimmyGarrido's response here to get a resolution: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/89661/a-lot-of-warnings-appear-in-a-new-empty-xamarin-forms-xaml-project

The simple answer in my case was to remove the PCLAppConfig Nuget package. There may be other packages in your project which were built using an old version of the Xamarin.Android.Support* packages. Unfortunately I haven't found a way of diagnosing which package specifically causes the problem, so updating, then removing and retesting one-by-one led me to the solution.